# Can't find recent announcement that the Flutter master branch can now enable flutter_web with command line operations

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I should have bookmarked it, but the googles aren't being helpful.

There was a recent (past week or so) that the standard `flutter` command on the master branch can now eliminate the difference between Flutter and flutter_web repositories.  This will be helpful for an upcoming demo.

Comment: Try `flutter config --enable-web` and then `flutter run -d chrome` (but you must switch to master branch)

Comment: Thank you!  I had just found that by trying "flutter help <command>" :)

Comment: Does it work as expected?

Comment: Yes, it worked fine!  I had the counter example in my chrome browser!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question is asking where the announcement link was, I bookmarked them. (Probably you don't need anymore though).

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-announce/-LQPz3C3JAM

https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/cl6cul/flutter_for_web_preview/

**Edited:**

I just tried the new approach and made some mistakes. So I would like to share more on this.

- Steps at Flutter (Channel master, v1.9.1-pre.91):

First create a new project:

```sh
flutter create --web project
```

OR

```sh
$ flutter create project
$ cd project
$ flutter create --web .
```

- Compile and Run the project with chrome (will launch chrome)

```sh
$ flutter run
```

That's all.

Another thing I found out: if you add the plugin which flutter web does not support, you can still pub get, compile successfully. The error will only happen when the unsupported code is triggered and then report some exceptions such as `NoSuchMethodError: '<Unexpected Null Value>'`.

Another Note: If you don't connect any mobile devices, `flutter run` by default will launch the chrome device. If you connect a mobile device, `flutter run` will pick the mobile device, compile and install it to your mobile device (at least it's the case in my env). So when you have both mobile and chrome devices, to launch the web case, simply execute `flutter run -d chrome`.

- More links:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34082

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Building-a-web-application-with-Flutter